# How to convert int to char without delete zero value

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert `int` to `varchar` in SQL Server without deleting zero value?

For example this query

```
Select CONVERT(varchar,002000089)
```

results in:

```
2000089
```

How can I get `002000089` as the query result?

Comment: `002000089` isn't an int, an int can't have preceding zero's. So you're trying to convert a string to a string.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: i am using sql server

Comment: Pick the right data type for your data. If you have something in which leading zeroes are relevant, then its a string of digits, *not* a number. Don't ever get it near an `int` variable/column, which is designed for storing numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to left pad them.  A pretty simple method is to use `format()`:

```
select format(002000089, '000000000')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two way to get the result `002000089` in sql-server

1. Append the converted result: `00` + CONVERT(varchar,002000089)

```
declare @intValue int=002000089
select '00'+ convert(varchar,@intValue)
```

2. I attach the converted result to my meta varchar value as `000000000` by `stuff`

```
declare @intValue int=002000089
declare @metaValue varchar(20)='000000000'
print stuff( @metaValue,
            len(@metaValue)-len(@intValue)+1,
            len(@intValue),
            cast(@intValue as varchar))
```